TreeTableView SelectionBar Bar Color Text
TreeTableView.
The selection bar follows a pattern and in MODENA the background of the bar is blue
and the color of the white letter.
When inside the cell using "update" it is placed for example
Orange in the color of the letter, when clicking on the line it does not appear
the letter with white color in the selection bar.
In this case, how can the selection remain in the default, that is,
with a blue background and white lettering.
"Without using CSS"

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView; 
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class SelectionBarColor extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
         TreeTableView<Person> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>();

        // Criar colunas
        TreeTableColumn<Person, String> nameColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Name");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().nameProperty());
         
        nameColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn<Person, String>, TreeTableCell<Person, String>>() {

            @Override
            public TreeTableCell<Person, String> call(TreeTableColumn<Person, String> param) {

                TreeTableCell<Person, String> cell = new TreeTableCell<Person, String>() {
                    
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (item != null) {                            
                            setTextFill(Color.ORANGE);
                            setText(item);
                            
                        }else {
                            setText("");
                            setGraphic(null);
                        }
                    }
                };

                return cell;
            }
        });

        TreeTableColumn<Person, String> addressColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Address");
        addressColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().addressProperty());

        TreeTableColumn<Person, Number> ageColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Age");
        ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().ageProperty());
        
        ageColumn.setCellFactory((TreeTableColumn<Person, Number> param) -> {
            TreeTableCell<Person, Number> cell = new TreeTableCell<Person, Number>() {
                
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    
                    if(item != null) {
                        if(item.doubleValue() != -1) {
                            setTextFill(Color.BLUE);
                            // setStyle("-fx-text-fill: blue;");
                            setText(""+item.intValue());
                            setGraphic(null);
                        }else {
                            setText("");
                            setGraphic(null);
                        }
                        
                    }else {
                        setText("");
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
            };
            
            return cell;
         });
        
        nameColumn.setPrefWidth(150);
        addressColumn.setPrefWidth(200);
        ageColumn.setPrefWidth(100);
        

        // Adicionar colunas ao TreeTableView
        treeTableView.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, addressColumn, ageColumn);

        // Criar raiz e adicionar itens
        TreeItem<Person> rootItem = new TreeItem<>(new Person("Persons", "", -1));
        rootItem.getChildren().addAll(
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("Alice", "456 Park Ave", 25)),
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("Bob", "789 Broadway", 35)),
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("Carol", "987 Elm St", 40)),
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("John", "123 Main St", 40))
        );

        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        treeTableView.setRoot(rootItem);

        Scene scene = new Scene(treeTableView, 500, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX TreeTableView SelectionBar");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    
    
    public static class Person {
        private StringProperty name;
        private StringProperty address;
        private IntegerProperty age;

        public Person(String name, String address, int age) {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.address = new SimpleStringProperty(address);
            this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public StringProperty addressProperty() {
            return address;
        }

        public IntegerProperty ageProperty() {
            return age;
        }
    }
}


"Without using CSS" Why? The easiest way to do this is with CSS, and that's the way the API is designed to be used.

Well, I have a case here where I constantly need to call applyCSS() and layout(), to repaint things, and applyCSS() takes longer to update, anyway, if there's no way I'll accept the suggestion using CSS anyway

"I have a case here where I constantly need to call applyCSS() and layout(), to repaint things" Then you have things misconfigured. There is never a need to do this with a virtualized control.

What is a virtualized control?

Virtualized controls are controls which create cells to display the items, and reuse the cells on the fly (so they can support very large numbers of items without needing large numbers of cells, for performance reasons). ListView, TreeView, TableView, and TreeTableView are all virtualized controls.

Correct, I am aware of this concept, I just didn't know the name. It's just that these virtual controls are often at a level below, where there are many other CSS controls above. In the future I will post a question about this and show the delay and the need to call .appyCSS() and .layout()

If you're calling applyCSS() and layout() you're completely defeating the purpose of using these controls in the first place, because you're circumventing the performance design of the layout code. Those are workarounds: you would be far better fixing whatever problem is causing you to use those workarounds than avoiding using the intended API in order to avoid the performance cost of the workaround.

Because you have knowledge on the subject, I will take your suggestion into account and analyze the issue further. So using CSS what you recommend would be .tree-table-row-cell:selected > *{ -fx-text-fill: white; } ?

The intended way to do this is to use CSS. You can achieve this in CSS using the following:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SelectionBarColor extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TreeTableView<Person> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>();

        // Criar colunas
        TreeTableColumn<Person, String> nameColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Name");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().nameProperty());
        nameColumn.getStyleClass().add("name-column");



        TreeTableColumn<Person, String> addressColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Address");
        addressColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().addressProperty());

        TreeTableColumn<Person, Number> ageColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Age");
        ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().ageProperty());
        ageColumn.getStyleClass().add("age-column");

        ageColumn.setCellFactory(ttc -> new TreeTableCell<Person, Number>() {


                @Override
                public void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if(item != null && item.intValue() != -1) {
                            setText(item.toString());
                            setGraphic(null);
                    }else {
                        setText("");
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }


        });

        nameColumn.setPrefWidth(150);
        addressColumn.setPrefWidth(200);
        ageColumn.setPrefWidth(100);


        // Adicionar colunas ao TreeTableView
        treeTableView.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, addressColumn, ageColumn);

        // Criar raiz e adicionar itens
        TreeItem<Person> rootItem = new TreeItem<>(new Person("Persons", "", -1));
        rootItem.getChildren().addAll(
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("Alice", "456 Park Ave", 25)),
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("Bob", "789 Broadway", 35)),
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("Carol", "987 Elm St", 40)),
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("John", "123 Main St", 40))
        );

        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        treeTableView.setRoot(rootItem);

        Scene scene = new Scene(treeTableView, 500, 300);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX TreeTableView SelectionBar");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }



    public static class Person {
        private StringProperty name;
        private StringProperty address;
        private IntegerProperty age;

        public Person(String name, String address, int age) {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.address = new SimpleStringProperty(address);
            this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public StringProperty addressProperty() {
            return address;
        }

        public IntegerProperty ageProperty() {
            return age;
        }
    }
}

(note there is no cell factory for the name column, and that the cell factory for the age column does not change the text color, but that the code adds CSS style classes to the two columns).
The stylesheet is
.name-column.tree-table-cell {
    -fx-mid-text-color: orange;
}
.age-column.tree-table-cell {
    -fx-mid-text-color: blue;
}

How this works:
The default CSS, modena, uses a color ladder function as the default text color for cells in a tree table view. The function is defined in modena as
    -fx-text-background-color: ladder(
        -fx-background,
        -fx-light-text-color 45%,
        -fx-dark-text-color  46%,
        -fx-dark-text-color  59%,
        -fx-mid-text-color   60%
    );

This function defines -fx-text-background-color as being dependent on -fx-background, setting it to -fx-light-text-color when the intensity of -fx-background is less than 45% (i.e. the background is dark), to -fx-dark-text-color when the intensity of -fx-background is between 46% and 59% (the background is medium), and -fx-mid-text-color when the intensity of -fx-background is above 60% (the background is light). The values of the looked-up colors -fx-light-text-color, -fx-mid-text-color, and -fx-dark-text-color are defined to be white, #333, and black, respectively. The effect is to select a text color that contrasts with the background.
The default background is a "very light gray" (it is 26.4% lighter than #ececec), which selects -fx-mid-text-color as the text fill. When the row is selected, the background is set to #0096c9, which is less than 45% intensity and so the text fill is set to -fx-light-text-color (white).
By replacing only the looked-up color -fx-mid-text-color in the column, you replace the text color for the default background, but leave the text color for the selected background unchanged. You could override -fx-light-text-color if you wanted, in order to create a different look for those columns when the row was selected.

Additionally, note that style classes applied to table columns are propagated to the cells in the column. The style class also applies to the column header. The selector .name.tree-table-cell { } selects elements with both the style class name and the style class tree-table-cell; i.e. it selects the cells in the column. If you use the selector .name { }, it will also color the text in the column header, which may or may not be desirable.
.name-column {
    -fx-mid-text-color: orange;
}
.age-column {
    -fx-mid-text-color: blue;
}



Without using CSS.
If you really want to do this without using CSS, it is possible but the code becomes more complex. Additionally, you do not get the proper separation of the style from the logic.
The way to do this is to let the custom cells observe the selected state of the row in which they are contained. JavaFX 19 and later versions have a flatMap() method that allow you to easily observe a "property of a property". The cells must update the text fill whenever the updateItem() method is called, and whenever the selection status of the row in which they are contained changes. One possible implementation looks like:
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TreeTableView<Person> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>();

        // Criar colunas
        TreeTableColumn<Person, String> nameColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Name");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().nameProperty());
//        nameColumn.getStyleClass().add("name-column");

        nameColumn.setCellFactory(ttc -> new TreeTableCell<Person, String>() {

            {
                tableRowProperty().flatMap(TreeTableRow::selectedProperty).addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> updateTextFill());
            }

            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {

                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item != null) {
                    setText(item);

                }else {
                    setText("");
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
                updateTextFill();
            }

            private void updateTextFill() {
                setTextFill(getTableRow().isSelected() ? Color.WHITE : Color.ORANGE);
            }
        });

        TreeTableColumn<Person, String> addressColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Address");
        addressColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().addressProperty());

        TreeTableColumn<Person, Number> ageColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Age");
        ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().ageProperty());
//        ageColumn.getStyleClass().add("age-column");

        ageColumn.setCellFactory(ttc -> new TreeTableCell<Person, Number>() {

            {
                tableRowProperty().flatMap(TreeTableRow::selectedProperty).addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> updateTextFill());
            }

                @Override
                public void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if(item != null && item.intValue() != -1) {
                            setText(item.toString());
                            setGraphic(null);
                    }else {
                        setText("");
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                    updateTextFill();
                }

                private void updateTextFill() {
                    setTextFill(getTableRow().isSelected() ? Color.WHITE: Color.BLUE);
                }

        });

        nameColumn.setPrefWidth(150);
        addressColumn.setPrefWidth(200);
        ageColumn.setPrefWidth(100);


        // Adicionar colunas ao TreeTableView
        treeTableView.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, addressColumn, ageColumn);

        // Criar raiz e adicionar itens
        TreeItem<Person> rootItem = new TreeItem<>(new Person("Persons", "", -1));
        rootItem.getChildren().addAll(
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("Alice", "456 Park Ave", 25)),
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("Bob", "789 Broadway", 35)),
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("Carol", "987 Elm St", 40)),
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("John", "123 Main St", 40))
        );

        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        treeTableView.setRoot(rootItem);

        Scene scene = new Scene(treeTableView, 500, 300);
//        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX TreeTableView SelectionBar");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

